# BiqQuery Storage. Python. Reading multiple streams in parallel issue (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, multiprocessing, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use BALANCED ShardingStrategy to get more then 1 stream and python multiprocessing lib to read stream in parallel.

However, when reading streams in parallel the same rows number and data is returned. As, if I understand correctly, no data is assigned to any stream before it starts reading and is finalized, so two parallel streams try to read same data and a part of data is never read as a result.

Using LIQUID strategy we can read all the data from one stream, which cannot be split.

According to documentation it is possible to read multiple streams in parallel with BALANCED one. However, I cannot figure out how to read in parallel and to assign different data to each stream

I have the following toy code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
import os
import google.auth
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='key.json'
credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
bq_storage_client = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(credentials=credentials)

table_ref = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReference()
table_ref.project_id = "bigquery-public-data"
table_ref.dataset_id = "ethereum_blockchain"
table_ref.table_id = "contracts"

parent = "projects/{}".format(your_project_id)
session = bq_storage_client.create_read_session(
    table_ref,
    parent,
    format_=bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.DataFormat.ARROW,
    sharding_strategy=(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.ShardingStrategy.BALANCED),
)

def read_rows(stream_position, session=session):
    reader = bq_storage_client.read_rows(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=session.streams[stream_position]), timeout=100000).to_arrow(session).to_pandas()
    return reader

if __name__ ==  '__main__': 
    p = Pool(2)
    output = p.map(read_rows,([i for i in range(0,2)]))
    print(output)
```

Need assistance to have multiple streams being read in parallel. 
Probably there is a way to assign data to a stream before the reading starts. Any examples of code or explanations and tips would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe [dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/samples#apache_beam_cloud_dataflow) could help you here; the official docs states it already offers supports for this API (but couldn't find this reference in apache beam docs so can't confirm).

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for the partial answer, but it didn't fit in a comment.

LIQUID or BALANCED just affect how data is allocated to streams, not the fact that data arrives in multiple streams (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1#shardingstrategy)).

When I ran a variant of your code with this read_rows function, I saw different data for the first row of both streams, so I was otherwise unable to replicate your problem with seeing the same data on this dataset with either shading strategy.

```
def read_rows(stream_position, session=session):
    reader = bq_storage_client.read_rows(
      bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=session.streams[stream_position]),timeout=100000)

    for row in reader.rows(session):
      print(row)
      break
```

I was running this code on a Linux compute engine instance.

I do worry that the output you are asking for in the map call is otherwise going to be quite large, however.

Comment: In LIQUID all data can be read from 1 stream, despite the number of streams. In BALANCED the data is distributed between multiple streams if the size of data/rows is big enough to split among streams. In other words, the fact that data arrives in multiple streams in BALANCED depends on the size of data only. In my example data is split into two streams (I intentially send an example with more then 1 stream). 

Data from the 1st row can be different but after reading is finished part of data will be the same and the total number of rows will be higher than expected. Thank you for your attempt